# Speed and multiple images

Tags: optics, speed, vision, perception

Why an object (or something else) create multiple images of itself when it is moving fast? An earphone spinning in circle for example.

Comment: How do you see multiple images? By eyesight or via a camera?

Comment: Outdoors, indoors, or both?

Comment: Why would would it matter whether you are standing inside or outside?

Comment: My guess. outside with sun: only blur. indoor: maybe a modulated light source and many images.

Comment: this may hapen without camera, particularly in case of superposition of 2 cyclic images and in case of a shadow effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fast moving object (not emitting light) is illuminated by a steady light source like the sun (i.e its intensity is not strongly modulated in time), then you should see a continuous blur, not discrete images. If you can distinguish different images, my guess is that your light source is modulated. I can see different images weaving my hand in front of the computer screen (modulated at 60Hz), but I see a continuous blur if I do it in front of a incandescent light bulb (which has some residual modulation at 50Hz, but small). 
More details in [flicker fusion threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold). The principle is the same that gives this cool effect [(video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGy0neDXxAE) (but here the object itself emits pulsed light).

Comment: Are you saying that the frame rate at which you record (even with your eyes) doesn't contribute to this effect? If you would record at really high fps you you would expect to see a more or less continuous image.

Comment: In addition: the reason you see a blur is because your eyes record images at around 200 fps. Which is also why we can see the flickering of the pulsed light source at 50-60Hz.

Comment: @David VdH I guess treating the eye and perception 100% as a camera can be misleading. I found interesting [this](http://www.100fps.com/how_many_frames_can_humans_see.htm), and the link in the answer.

Comment: I took a look at the limk myself. I didn't mean to say that your statement was wrong, my apologies if that is what my comment seemed to imply. However I felt like the answer is incomplete as the question doesn't specify if a camera is or isn't used. You only elaborate on the cause of the effect when looking at it directly. Which is the reason I based my answer based on using a camera.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer focuses on the cause of the effect in case a camera is used.**

For what follows I'll assume the object in question is illuminated by a continuous light source. Otherwise the multiple images are of course due to the flickering of the lamp.

The reason you see multiple images is because the sampling rate (the rate at which images are "recorded", so the frame rate for a camera) is lower than the speed of the object. Therefore  in between two images or frames the object moves but you do not observe this movement. So alternatively to your statement:

> A moving object creates multiple images.

You could say:

> The method of recording creates gaps in a continuous image.

Note that the higher the fps the more images you will see and the closer these images will lie together.